# What do I call the horizontal part of a piece of equipment in a cleanroom on which tweezers are placed?

Tags: translation, technical

I'm translating a Russian document about a vial filling/stoppering/crimping line located in a cleanroom environment. Now and then the instruction says that the operator should "place tweezers" or "place settling plates" on the filling (or crimping) machine's **stanina** (станина). This is a Russian word that [has a bevy of possible translations into English, according to Multitran](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%F1%F2%E0%ED%E8%ED%E0). The basic definition of "stanina" is "the non-moving part of a machine". This is quite vague, and thus hard to translate.

I asked the authors for a photo of this "stanina" on which they place their tweezers for later using them to grab stray vials. The photo is attached below. It's basically a flat portion of a machine. A laminar flow hood is overhanging it somewhere above. In my draft version I'm using the term **frame** for it, like "place the tweezers on the **frame** of the machine in the two specified points, for further use".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked worked with radioactive isotopes under extreme conditions, I would say that tweezers would be placed under the draught of the extractor, but not confined in any way and not touching anything else.

I strongly suspect that '*stanina*' means just 'surface'.

The tweezers are placed on the flat surface of the machine under the extractor hood so that the extraction system will draw any fibres off the tweezers and no detritus will adhere to a tray or cup.

Comment: I've worked in a cleanroom for many years and agree that "Place the tweezers on the clean surface of the machine (at one of the two specified points under the laminar flow hood)." sounds more natural than "Place the tweezers on the frame of the machine...", in part because "frame" can also refer to an internal structure.